# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sur

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and constructed my jar from IntelliJ. I get following error when I run it as a standalone application.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:470) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:180) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationEntry(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:123) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:434) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:879) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[dronedelivery.jar:1.3.5]
```

Comment: could you, please, publish your META-INF file?

Comment: I have a META-INF folder inside my jar. did you want to see the contents of that folder?

Comment: One observation: if I use mvn clean install from powershell. the jar works fine. however the jar generated by IntelliJ gives above error